# findFirst on a Stream<Optional<T>>

Tags: java, java-stream, option-type

Say you've got a stream of `Optional<T>`, that you want to fire a `Consumer<T>` on (if present).

What's the most elegant way of handling this?

I can manage by filtering by `Optional::isPresent` and mapping by `Optional::isGet`, but that seems "hacky" and not in the spirit of `Optional`:

```
Stream.of(a, b, c, d)
   .filter(Optional::isPresent)
   .map(Optional::get)
   .findFirst()
   .ifPresent(s -> System.out.println("This was cumbersome: " + s));
```

Comment: I guess what annoys me this is that Optional already has Optional::flatMap and a whole lot of the construct is about avoiding explicit testing. Moreover, I could write this code with a for loop in just as many lines!

Comment: Then why not simply use a for loop?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I agree that it's cumbersome but it's probably about the most straightforward solution without getting even more hacky.

One thing I've done in a similar situation is to create a method to turn an `Optional` into a `Stream`:

```
private Stream<T> optionalStream(Optional<T> optional) {
    if (optional.isPresent())
        return Stream.of(optional.get());
    else
        return Stream.empty());
}
```

So you can then use `flatMap`:

```
Stream.of(a, b, c, d)
    .flatMap(this::optionalStream).findFirst()...
```

From Java 9 the `Stream` method has been added to `Optional` to do exactly this so you can use:

```
Stream.of(a, b, c, d)
    .flatMap(Optional::stream)
    .findFirst()...
```

But to be honest I'm not sure this is all that much simpler than your `filter` then `map` solution.

Comment: Note that such method is [added in JDK9](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/dev/jdk/file/f160dec9a350/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/Optional.java#l282), so you will be able to do simply `.flatMap(Optional::stream)`.

Comment: @TagirValeev thanks for that find. They must have been looking at my code :-) Looking forward to 9 being released.

Answer (score 1):

I think flatMap can be really handy here

```
 Stream.of(a, b, c, d)
   .flatMap(opt -> opt.map(Stream::of).orElse(Stream.empty()))
   .findFirst()
   .ifPresent(s -> System.out.println("This was cumbersome: " + s));
```

Not ideal, but at least concise.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if either approach below is better than yours...

First, you could try with `reduce()`:

```
Stream.of(a, b, c, d).reduce(Optional.empty(), (o1, o2) -> o1.isPresent() ? o1 : o2)
    .ifPresent(s -> System.out.println("This seems cumbersome as well: " + s));
```

You'd still be querying the `Optional`, though this would happen while reducing the stream.

A more elegant approach (though not less verbose) would be to use a specialized `Consumer` that would accept the `Optional`'s value only when non-empty. For this, you'd need to define your `OptionalConsumer` as follows:

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface OptionalConsumer<T>
    extends Consumer<Optional<T>> {

    @Override
    default void accept(Optional<T> o) {
        if (o.isPresent()) {
            this.acceptIfPresent(o.get());
        }
    }

    void acceptIfPresent(T o);

    static <U> OptionalConsumer<U> of(Consumer<U> c) {
        return c::accept;
    }
}
```

And you could use it this way:

```
Stream.of(a, b, c, d).forEach(OptionalConsumer.of(s -> System.out.println("Better? " + s)));
```

Notes:

1. Maybe this approach is better when you need to perform this same logic in many different streams.
2. I wouldn't bet it works well on parallel streams.
3. As `OptionalConsumer` is actually a `Consumer`, I don't see how you could use it along with `findFirst()`.